# Update Date Format for Multiple Dates in File

Tags: bash, date, unix, awk

I'm trying to update a file with multiple dates. Here is an example file:

```
firstname   lastname    startdate   enddate
bob smith   6/1/2014    6/30/2014
sue jones   5/31/2014   6/15/2014
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
firstname   lastname    startdate   enddate
bob smith   20140601 0000   20140630 0000
sue jones   20140531 0000   20140615 0000
```

I can get the first date just fine using `awk`, but the second date ends up on a second line.

```
$ awk -F '\t' 'NR <=1 {print;next} {printf("%s\t%s\t",$1,$2);system("date -j -f '%m/%d/%Y' "$3" +%Y%m%d\\ 0000");system("date -j -f '%m/%d/%Y' "$4" +%Y%m%d\\ 0000");}' dates.txt 

firstname   lastname    startdate   enddate
bob smith   20140601 0000
20140630 0000
sue jones   20140531 0000
20140615 0000
```

I can't find any examples where someone is trying to change two dates in a file. Can someone please help me figure out how to get the output of each line on one line?

Comment: I would actually just go through the file, search for the pattern and replace it accordingly: `sed 's/\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\)\/\([0-9]\+\)/\3\2\1 0000/g' test.txt`  
However, the solution isn't quite ideal, since you want a leading zero as well (I am not very good in bash). It might give you an idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ awk -F'[ \t/]+' 'NR==1{print;next;} {printf "%s %s  %04i%02i%02i 0000  %04i%02i%02i 0000\n",$1,$2,$5,$3,$4,$8,$6,$7;}' dates.txt
firstname   lastname    startdate   enddate
bob smith  20140601 0000  20140630 0000
sue jones  20140531 0000  20140615 0000
```

This was tested under GNU awk but I expect it to be portable to other awks.

#### How it works

- `-F'[ \t/]+'`

  This sets the field separator to any combination of blank, tab, or slash.  This way, we can access the years, months, and days as separate fields.  You may need to change this if it doesn't accurately represent the field separators in your actual input file.
- `NR==1{print;next;}`

  The header line is printed as is.
- `printf "%s %s  %04i%02i%02i 0000  %04i%02i%02i 0000\n",$1,$2,$5,$3,$4,$8,$6,$7;`

  All lines after the first are reformatted usign a `printf` statement.  You may adjust the format string to produce whatever your prefer.  In particular, if your fields are tab-separated, you will want to add tabs.

#### Tab-separated version

If the input and output are to be tab-separated:

```
$ awk -F'[\t/]+' 'NR==1{print;next;} {printf "%s\t%s\t%04i%02i%02i 0000\t%04i%02i%02i 0000\n",$1,$2,$5,$3,$4,$8,$6,$7;}' dates.txt
firstname       lastname        startdate       enddate
bob     smith   20140601 0000   20140630 0000
sue     jones   20140531 0000   20140615 0000
```

In the above, I assumed that `20140601 0000` is to be treated as one field.  If not, then the part of the format string with `0000` will need to be replaced with `\t0000`.

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! I guess one issue I have is in my actual file, I have a column with spaces in it. Would it be possible to do this without using spaces as a field separator? Also can you share an example of how to print as tab-separated? Does that go in the quotes, or outside of it?

Comment: @shawtydubs Very good.  I updated the answer with a section for tab-separated input and output.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=3; i<=4; i++) {
        $i = (split($i,a,"/")>2 ? sprintf("%04d%02d%02d 000",a[3],a[1],a[2]) : $i)
    }
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
firstname       lastname        startdate       enddate
bob     smith   20140601 000    20140630 000
sue     jones   20140531 000    20140615 000
```

Comment: Plus one for a solution that allows the first two fields to include a `/`.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't need a system call for rearranging date fields.  However for other uses there is an alternative `gawk` solution.

If you need to call another process and trap the output in the script you can use this idiom

```
"subprogram" |& getline results
```

for your case

```
awk -F'\t' -vOFS='\t' '
       NR==1{print;next} 
            {"date -j -f '%m/%d/%Y' "$3" +%Y%m%d\\ 0000" |& getline d1;
             "date -j -f '%m/%d/%Y' "$4" +%Y%m%d\\ 0000" |& getline d2;
             print $1,$2,d1,d2}' file
```

Comment: The idiom is `results=""; cmd="subprogram"; if ((cmd |& getline results) > 0) { use results } close(cmd)`. See http://awk.info/?tip/getline.